# What is the equivalent class for GrailsControllerHandlerMapping in Grails3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I was migrating a grails2 plugin to the grails3, There is a class

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsControllerHandlerMapping
```

in grails2.x version, I did not find this class in grails3.

Has this class has been replaced with any other class, or it just has been removed?

There are 2 more classes which I did not find in grails3, these are

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.metaclass.BeanBinding
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.metaclass.PropertyExpression
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent of `GrailsControllerHandlerMapping` this area has been refactored and is now implemented as `UrlMappingsHandlerMapping`

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-url-mappings/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/mapping/mvc/UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.groovy

The `metaclass` package has also been removed as all metaprogramming has been replaced by the use of Traits.